# Update Code by Jenkins File automatically

Tags: xml, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have my source code and inside that I have Jenkinsfile, I use jenkinsfile to deploy my source code to ec2.

my code structure:

```
apiSourceCode
  - folder1
  - folder2
      - file.xml
  - Jenkinsfile
  - README.md
```

With above jenkinsfile I deploy my code to ec2, this jenkinsfile identify new changes in source code automatically and deploy those changes to ec2.

file.xml content

```
<site_name>google.com</site_name>
```

My Goal/Requirement is below:

I want to update **folder1/file.xml** with some content let's say **<site_name>yahoo.com</site_name>**
but want to update via jenkinsfile env variable.

so basically I will pass **site_name** in env variable of jenkinsfile and that **site_name** should get updated in **file.xml** in some stage let's say INIT stage and then subsequent stage let's say BUILD should follow automatically.
Is it possible to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to get 1000 different suggestions  with `find` and `sed` and some perl you'll never figure out how it works.

You don't mention a language tag or build tool tag, but if you use maven to build, consider [`mvn replacer-plugin:replace`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/maven-replacer-plugin).

Or you can define it as a maven property in the pom.xml, then you can override with a command-line parameter at build time: `mvn -D=site_name=yahoo.com install`

Comment: I am not using maven or gradle, I just have set of XMLs

Comment: Then be ready for the `find` / `sed` / `perl` solves everything / you should not edit XML with anything other than XML tools like  [`XSLT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10770050/598141) flame wars.